NGINX reverse proxy SSL passthrough not working with long hostnames

TL;DR while the SSL passthrough configuration may still interest some curious, the issue was simply a typo in one of the port for all the long hostnames I tested.

I'm trying to pass through https traffic to a backend server via the Nginx stream module. It works for reasonably sized URLs but not with longer one, but I cannot figure out how to solve the issue.
I can reach every URLs of my backend reverse proxy from the front reverse proxy using /etc/hosts to resolve the address and specifying the port (9443). So I'm certain the backend reverse proxy is correctly configured.
For these domains (I obviously changed the URLs, but the sizes are the same), there are no issues:
wordpress.com 127.0.0.1:9443;
www.wordpress.com 127.0.0.1:9443;
crm.exemplexx.com 127.0.0.1:9443;
# Point to the same endpoint as the long domain
sd.wordpress.com 127.0.0.1:9443;

Errors and logs
For the longer ones, I get a connection refused error (2024/08/04 12:30:00 [error] 65636#65636: *34 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while proxying connection, client: 42.252.189.66, server: 0.0.0.0:443, upstream: "127.0.0.1:9433", bytes from/to client:314/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0) :
# I only need the first one, the other were for testing purposes
enormousubdomainname.dm-ricks.com 127.0.0.1:9433;
enormousubdomainname.wordpress.com 127.0.0.1:9433;
enormousu-bdomainname.wordpress.com 127.0.0.1:9433;
    
# I know these are commented now,
# but they are not mapping correcly
# ~*.dm\-ricks.com  127.0.0.1:9433;
# *.dm-ricks.com  127.0.0.1:9443;

In Firefox, I get this error, since it never receives the certificate:
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to enormousubdomainname.dm-ricks.com. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

Error code: PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

For the long URLs I get the following logs:
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [info] 65636#65636: *34 client 42.252.189.66:48959 connected to 0.0.0.0:443
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 posix_memalign: 0000598DEC52CAD0:256 @16
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 posix_memalign: 0000598DEC52CCA0:256 @16
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 generic phase: 0
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 generic phase: 1
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 generic phase: 2
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 generic phase: 3
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 generic phase: 4
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 ssl preread handler
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 posix_memalign: 0000598DEC52C6D0:256 @16
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 malloc: 0000598DEC51C8D0:16384
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 stream recv(): -1
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 epoll add event: fd:67 op:1 ev:80002001
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 event timer add: 67: 30000:85946214
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: epoll del event: fd:8 op:2 ev:00000000
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: epoll add event: fd:8 op:1 ev:10000001
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 stream recv(): 314
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 ssl preread handler
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 ssl preread: state 0 left 0
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 ssl preread: supported_versions
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 SSL preread server name: "enormousubdomainname.dm-ricks.com"
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 event timer del: 67: 85946214
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 tcp_nodelay
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 proxy connection handler
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 malloc: 0000598DEC5208E0:448
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 malloc: 0000598DEC61B510:16384
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 post event 0000598DEC5EB610
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 stream map started
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 stream script var: "enormousubdomainname.dm-ricks.com"
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 posix_memalign: 0000598DEC52C5C0:256 @16
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 stream map: "enormousubdomainname.dm-ricks.com" "127.0.0.1:9433"
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 stream script var: "127.0.0.1:9433"
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 posix_memalign: 0000598DEC520AB0:256 @16
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 malloc: 0000598DEC520BC0:384
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 get rr peer, try: 1
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 stream socket 68
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 epoll add connection: fd:68 ev:80002005
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 connect to 127.0.0.1:9433, fd:68 #35
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 proxy connect: -2
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 event timer add: 68: 5000:85921235
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 delete posted event 0000598DEC5EB610
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 recv: fd:67 314 of 16384
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 event timer del: 68: 85921235
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 stream proxy connect upstream
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [error] 65636#65636: *34 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while proxying connection, client: 42.252.189.66, server: 0.0.0.0:443, upstream: "127.0.0.1:9433", bytes from/to client:314/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 stream proxy next upstream
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 free rr peer 1 4
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 finalize stream proxy: 502
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 close stream proxy upstream connection: 68
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 reusable connection: 0
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 finalize stream session: 502
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 stream log handler
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 posix_memalign: 0000598DEC520D50:256 @16
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 close stream connection: 67
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 reusable connection: 0
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 free: 0000598DEC520BC0
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 free: 0000598DEC61B510
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 free: 0000598DEC5208E0
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 free: 0000598DEC51C8D0
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 free: 0000598DEC52A7F0, unused: 0
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 free: 0000598DEC52C8D0, unused: 0
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 free: 0000598DEC52CAD0, unused: 8
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 free: 0000598DEC52CCA0, unused: 0
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 free: 0000598DEC52C6D0, unused: 6
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 free: 0000598DEC52C5C0, unused: 0
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 free: 0000598DEC520AB0, unused: 2
2024/08/04 12:30:00 [debug] 65636#65636: *34 free: 0000598DEC520D50, unused: 56

Configuration
I'm using the latest version of nginx with the stream module.
$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.27.0

With more or less this configuration.
$ sudo nginx -T
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        client_max_body_size 128M;

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
        server_names_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

stream {
  log_format log_stream '$remote_addr [$time_local] $protocol [$ssl_preread_server_name] [$ssl_preread_alpn_protocols] '
      '$status $bytes_sent $bytes_received $session_time';

  error_log   /var/log/nginx/stream.error.log debug;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/stream.access.log log_stream;

  map_hash_bucket_size 128;
  map_hash_max_size 4096;

  map $ssl_preread_server_name $target_backend {
    enormousubdomainname.dm-ricks.com 127.0.0.1:9433;
    enormousubdomainname.wordpress.com 127.0.0.1:9433;
    enormousu-bdomainname.wordpress.com 127.0.0.1:9433;
    wordpress.com 127.0.0.1:9443;
    www.wordpress.com 127.0.0.1:9443;
    crm.exemplexx.com 127.0.0.1:9443;
    sd.wordpress.com 127.0.0.1:9443;
    # ~*.dm\-ricks.com  127.0.0.1:9433;
    # *.dm-ricks.com  127.0.0.1:9443;
  }

  server {
    listen 443;

    proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
    proxy_timeout 5s;
    # resolver 1.1.1.1;

    proxy_pass $target_backend;
    ssl_preread on;
  }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

# [default configuration]

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/crm.exemplexx.com:
upstream crm  {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name crm.exemplexx.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass         http://crm;
                #proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                #proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/wordpress.com:
upstream wordpress  {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name     wordpress.com www.wordpress.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass         http://wordpress;
                #proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                #proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sd.dm-ricks.com:
upstream sd  {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name    sd.dm-ricks.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass         http://sd;
                #proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                #proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/enormousubdomainname.dm-ricks.com:
upstream enormousubdomainname  {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name    enormousubdomainname.dm-ricks.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass         http://enormousubdomainname;
                #proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                #proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        }
}

[...]
``


What does the proxy do when all sites are on the same server:port anyway?

The backend server is another reverse proxy in an isolated VM which also contains docker and LXC containers and the certificates.

You say the backend is on port 9443, but the entries that don't work (both long names and wildcard ones) are trying to use 9433. 9433 is not 9443, so it doesn't work.

@dave_thompson_085, you are right, it's working properly now.

As @dave_thompson_085 pointed out, I've simply used the wrong port (9433 instead of 9443).
